# Fill list box from another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I'm searching for this for several hours now and was not able to find proper solution. I'm c# beginner.

I have a winforms app with a ListBox and a class that does some work and should run forever on separate thread. I want to push **MyDataStruct** to ListBox each time its created in **WorkerClass.Work**.

Later on, several **WorkerClass** instances should run simultaneously and I will have combobox to pick which instance data to feed to ListBox . Is it better to have WorkerClas return only single MyDataStruct and keep their queue in **Form1** class or have a queue in each **WorkerClass** and exchange the entire queue with **Form1** every time it changes?

is my void QueueToLb good way to add queue data to ListBox ?

thank you for your support.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Queue<MyDataStruct> qList;
        MyDataStruct myDataStruct;
        private void RunTask()
        {
            //how do I make MyLongTask to update either qList or myDataStuct
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                MyLongTask(0, 1000);
            });
        }
        private void MyLongTask(int low, int high)
        {
            WorkerClass wc = new WorkerClass();
            wc.Work(low,high);           
        }
        private void QueueToLb()
        {
            //is this good way to update listbox from queue?
            List<MyDataStruct> lstMds = qList.Reverse<MyDataStruct>().ToList<MyDataStruct>();
            List<string> lstStr = new List<string>();
            foreach (MyDataStruct m in lstMds)
            {
                lstStr.Add(m.ToString());
            }
            listBox1.DataSource = lstStr;            
        }
    }

    public class WorkerClass
    {
        Queue<MyDataStruct> qList; //not sure if its better to keep the queue here or in Form1
        public WorkerClass()
        {
            qList = new Queue<MyDataStruct>();
        }
        public void Work(int low, int high) //does some work forever
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (qList.Count > 11) qList.Dequeue();
                MyDataStruct mds = new MyDataStruct();
                Random random = new Random();
                mds.dt = DateTime.Now;
                mds.num = random.Next(low, high);
                qList.Enqueue(mds);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyDataStruct
    {
        public DateTime dt;
        public int num;
        public override string ToString()
        {
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            s.Append(num.ToString());
            s.Append(" - ");
            s.Append(dt.ToShortDateString());
            return s.ToString();
        }

    }
```

OK I think I figured how to use BackgroundWorker on this, I'll be happy if someone could verify it is correct

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Queue<MyDataStruct> qList;        
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;            
            bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(Bw_DoWork);
            bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);                        
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            qList = new Queue<MyDataStruct>(12);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void MyLongTask(int low = 0, int high = 1000)
        {
            WorkerClass wc = new WorkerClass(bw);
            wc.Work(low,high);           
        }

        private void BindToLbWithQueue()
        {            

            MyDataStruct mds = new MyDataStruct();
            Random random = new Random();
            mds.dt = DateTime.Now;
            mds.num = random.Next(0, 1000);

            qList.Enqueue(mds);
            QueueToLb();
        }

        private void QueueToLb()
        {
            //is this good way to update listbox from queue?
            List<MyDataStruct> lstMds = qList.Reverse<MyDataStruct>().ToList<MyDataStruct>();
            List<string> lstStr = new List<string>();
            foreach (MyDataStruct m in lstMds)
            {
                lstStr.Add(m.ToString());
            }
            listBox1.DataSource = lstStr;                        
        }

        #region worker
        private void Bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            MyLongTask();
        }

        private void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            qList = (Queue<MyDataStruct>)e.UserState;
            QueueToLb();
        }
        #endregion

    }

    public class WorkerClass
    {
        Queue<MyDataStruct> qList; //not sure if its better to keep the queue here or in Form1
        BackgroundWorker bw = null;
        public WorkerClass(BackgroundWorker bw)
        {
            this.bw = bw;
            qList = new Queue<MyDataStruct>();
        }

        public void Work(int low, int high) //does some work forever
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (qList.Count > 11) qList.Dequeue();
                MyDataStruct mds = new MyDataStruct();
                Random random = new Random();
                mds.dt = DateTime.Now;
                mds.num = random.Next(low, high);
                qList.Enqueue(mds);
                bw.ReportProgress(0, qList);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyDataStruct
    {
        public DateTime dt;
        public int num;
        public override string ToString()
        {
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            s.Append(num.ToString());
            s.Append(" - ");
            s.Append(dt.ToShortDateString());
            return s.ToString();
        }

    }
```

Comment: `Task.Run()`? You might consider to use `BackgroundWorker`. _"Is it better to have [...] every time it changes?"_. Keep the queue on each `WorkerClass` otherwise you will need some synchronization mechanism. More than that, from code you posted you may drop `Queue<T>` and directly use `List<T>`.

Comment: _"is my void QueueToLb good way to add queue data to listbox?"_ It's one way, however I have some perplexities. You're converting result to a list of strings and then you assign to `DataSource`. Why don't you simply set the list to `Items` property? You already have `ToString()` in-place. Is it thread-safe? It depends where `QueueToLb()` is called...that's the problem with fictional examples...`Form.qList` is currently always empty.

Comment: I have to initiate the backgroundworker in Form1 and pass it to WorkerClass right? BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress accepts int32,  how to I report MyDataStruct instrance?

Comment: ReportProgress is to...report a progress, not to pass data between caller and callee. You use the BackgroundWorker as you're currently using the Task. The _advantage_ is to have completition (and eventually notifications) events automatically called in the right thread.

Comment: could you pretty please show me an example?

Comment: Just use the `IProgress` class and `Task.Run`, google the sample code.